# Ember JSONAPIAdapter server reject response format?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am using JSONAPIAdapter in Ember Data, in case server wants to reject the request, server returns HTTP status code 400 Bad Request with json payload like this:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"698","title":"Invalid request"}]}
```

According to the jsonapi.org, I think this is the correct format( a array of error objects keyed by "errors" )

But when I run Ember, I always get a Adapter error. Is my format incorrect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting `AdapterError` is correct behavior in this case. You can see that your payload from the server is correctly parsed by Ember and `errors` property of Error object you've logged is populated.

So, your adapter tries for example to get some records, but instead it gets `400` error and it's expected that you will get `AdapterError`.

If you don't want to get `AdapterError` you have to change the way your server behaves and instead of rejecting request provide model data.

You can also catch `AdapterError` if this is expected for you and handle that manually.